# Is there character spacing feature in PDFpen?

Tags: pdf

I am trying out the demo version of PDFpen and can't figure out a way to adjust the character spacing. My text edit ended up like this:

The first line is a result from PDFpen editing and the second line is the original.
Please avoid obvious suggestion like using a different font.

I like to know if character spacing is available or not in PDFpen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, select the text, and choose `Format -> Font -> Kern -> Loosen` from the menu.

If you need to do this frequently, visit the Keyboard Shortcuts tab of the Keyboard system preferences, then select Application Shortcuts and add a shortcut for Loosen.

Like any customer of ours, you can also email support@smilesoftware.com